# Extra argument in call when try to call convenience init, Swift

Tags: swift

I have simple class:

```
class WmAttendee{

    var mEmail:String!
    var mName:String!
    var mType:Int!
    var mStatus:String = "0"
    var mRelationShip:String!

    init( email:String, name:String, type:Int) {
        self.mEmail = email
        self.mName = name
        self.mType = type
    }

     convenience init( email:String,  name:String,  type:Int,  status:String, relationShip:String) {
        self.init(email: email, name: name, type: type)
        self.mStatus = status
        self.mRelationShip = relationShip
    }
}
```

When I try to test 2nd constructor with 5 parameters, I get: `Extra argument 'status' in call`

```
var att1 = WmAttendee(email: "myMail", name: "SomeName", type: 1); // OK

var att2 = WmAttendee(email: "mail2", name: "name2", type: 3, status: "2", relationShip: 3)
 // ERROR Extra argument 'status' in call
```

Why? Do I miss something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your method signature:

```
convenience init( email:String,  name:String,  type:Int,  status:String, relationShip:String)
```

`relationshipStatus` should be a `String` and not an `Int`:

```
var att2 = WmAttendee(email: "mail2", name: "name2", type: 3, status: "2", relationShip: "3")
```

Since you're not passing the correct type for `relationshipStatus`, the compiler can't match the method signature for your convenience init and falls back the the default init (the closest match it can find) which triggers the `Extra argument` error.

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing a parameter of the wrong type to your function. 'RelationShip' must be of type String, but you are passing an Integer. Yes, the compiler error is misleading, but then again swift is still in beta.